# Deep Learning and FEM diagram in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

More than a year ago, I published the following open-source article: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0045782521007374

Currently, I am writing my Ph.D. dissertation, where such article is involved. I would like to improve the sketch/diagram given in Fig. 1 of the aforementioned publication that I display below:

[image: Fig. 1 in the original publication]

Since all the other graphics included in my dissertation are in Tikz, I would also like this one to be in that elegant format. However, I really find it extremely difficult! I would like a reproducible code to input into my dissertation so that the figure is generated according to the typographic style of the thesis.

If any of you could help me with this task, I would really appreciate it. Of course, I would include your (nick)name in the dissertation as an acknowledgment of your effort.

Comment: Here's a science oriented Tikz gallery: https://tikz.net/science/ with both images and code. // Try also https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=deep+learning .

Answer (score 2):

Here's a manual quick-and-dirty approach.

Just some rectangles and a grid with the help of the `3d` library for the `canvas is AB plane at C` keys.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d, shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  line join=round,
  z=(135:.8cm), sh/.style={shift={(0,0,#1)}},
  sides/.style={fill=lightgray}]
\sffamily
\foreach \i in {4, 3, 2, 1}{
  \tikzset{sh=\i}
  \fill[white] (0,0) rectangle coordinate(@) (3,2);
  \draw[line cap=rect, xstep=3/(2^\i), ystep=2/(2^\i)] (0,0) grid (3,2);
}
\node[below] at (@|-0,0) {FEM refinements};

\tikzset{shift=(right:7)}

\foreach \i in {4, 3, 2, 1}{
  \tikzset{sh=\i}
  \draw[sides, canvas is yz plane at x=0]
    (0,0) rectangle (1.5,.5) coordinate (@);
  \draw[sides, canvas is xz plane at y=1.5]
    (@) rectangle node[transform shape, yscale=.75] {Layer \i}
                  (4,0) coordinate (@);
  \draw[fill=white] (0,0) rectangle coordinate(@) (@);
}
\node[below] at (@|-0,0) {NN layers};

\node[single arrow, draw, fill=white, minimum height=3cm,
      canvas is yz plane at x=0, rotate=90] at (0, .75, 2.75) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]